# Rails tables association Edit pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confronted with this issue:

I have a users table, and I am about to create an articles table and a pictures table.

Yes, articles depends on users and pictures depends on articles. I mean that a user can have many articles and each article can have many pictures.

I already have the Users table and I know that I could create a Model for Articles and another for Pictures and write in there belongs_to and in the parent tables, has_many.

The question is, if I declare a full Resource for Articles and a full resource for Pictures, each will get its own Edit page of their own, however, they are interrelated, so if the user wants to Edit his article changing some text but also replacing some pictures, I have 2 Edit pages, one from Articles, one for Pictures. I would have to have only 1 that contains Fields for everything, just as I would want to have when the User Creates a new Article.

Should I create the resource for Articles and Pictures without the Edit option ? and create a "hand made" Edit page?

How do you go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you would only need a Articles recsouces, because you are doing CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) on your Articles not picture. Article is the prime object, picture depends on it. If a user need to edit a picture you can do that in your Article edit page. I recommend creating a handmade edit page for Article.

> User has_many articles
>
> Article belongs_to user
>
> Article has_many pictures
>
> Pictures belongs_to article

Comment: but think that I can have any number of Pictures. This means that pictures has to have its own separate table. Is it still valid your indication?

Comment: I understand, I forgot to add that. Sorry. Obviously picture need it's model)and table), what I meant was you don't need to have a Edit method for pictures.